# Converting list<Object []> into hashmap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to convert the below list object array into hashmap. After conversion I am getting only the second array element in the hashmap. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong in my code.

```
//List

List<Object[]> total =
    [
        [
            "01-08-2017",
            "A",
            "827",
            10
        ],
        [
            "12-07-2017",
            "A",
            "100",
            250
        ]
    ]


final Map<String, String> statsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (Object[] tuple : total) {
            statsMap.put("date", tuple[0].toString());
            statsMap.put("type", tuple[1].toString());
            statsMap.put("code", tuple[2].toString());
            statsMap.put("count", tuple[3].toString());
        }

//Output
{
"date":"12-07-2017",
"type":"A",
"code":"100",
"count":"250"
}
```

I am expecting output as below

```
[{
"date":"01-08-2017",
"type":"A",
"code":"827",
"count":"10"
},
{
"date":"12-07-2017",
"type":"A",
"code":"100",
"count":"250"
}]
```

Comment: A HashMap is a Key/Value system so not really adapted with your case, you have a precise idea ?

Comment: @azro Yes I do know, I am trying to convert the list into key value pair

Comment: ok, but what for key ? and what for value ? you have just array of 4 elements

Comment: It seems that you're just constantly overwriting every key.

Answer (score 0):

Remember hashmaps are essentially dictionaries, keys map to one value, multiple keys can map to the same value but keys cant map to multiple value with that in mind looking at this

```
statsMap.put("date", tuple[0].toString());
statsMap.put("type", tuple[1].
statsMap.put("code", tuple[2].toString());
statsMap.put("count", tuple[3].toString());
```

you use the same key each time. You have two Object[] in your List total. 
So on the first iteration it will look like this

```
"date":"01-08-2017",
"type":"A",
"code":"827",
"count":"10"
```

but then you go through a second iteration because remember two object[]

so you end up with

```
"date":"12-07-2017",
"type":"A",
"code":"100",
"count":"250"
```

You can try doing a `HashMap<String, List<String>>`

and instead of mapping the key to the object value, map the key to a list containing a list of the object values.

Answer (score 0):

As you loop through total, you are putting the same keys into the HashMap each pass. This effectively replaces the value of each key.

What you seem to want to do is to create a class that contains four properties, and then create a list of instances of that class.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the result you're looking for is a `List<Map<String, String>>`, i.e. a list of key-value pairs. Your code should look like the following in that case:

```
List<Object[]> total = ...;
final List<Map<String, String>> stats = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

for (Object[] tuple : total) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("date", tuple[0].toString());
    map.put("type", tuple[1].toString());
    map.put("code", tuple[2].toString());
    map.put("count", tuple[3].toString());
    stats.add(map);
}
```

Comment: If you actually read my post, you'll see that our answers are very different @azro

Comment: You even copy/paste the comment `//date1...` xD

Comment: You're right, I copied the inner part of my for loop from the wrong spot, my mistake. You code is no longer in my answer.